# Compile an "SQL Server Database Project" project in Visual Studio 2012 from command-line?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, command-line, compilation, database-project, sql-server-data-tools

What is the command-line to build an "SQL Server Database Project" project?

I try to google for this but I was filled with lots of posts on Visual Studio 2010 which is outdated.

Please share if you know how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Visual Studio Developer command prompt, navigate to the project folder and type `msbuild <projectname>.sqlproj`.

The default msbuild action is to build the project (it's possible to pass "/t:Build" in to explicitly call build).

From a non-developer command prompt you'd just need to add MSBuild to the path.

Comment: On a related note, I had some odd behavior when choosing to build just the sqlproj file - it always tried to do a deploy/publish as well. I ended up building the "sln" file and that just did the build as expected.

Comment: @peter-schott If you look at the Project element is the DefaultTargets set to "Build" or "Build;Deploy"? If it includes Deploy then it'll try to automatically deploy on build. Removing that should fix that issue (if present).
Also if the GenerateCreateScript property is "true" then it'll simulate deployment to a new database and generate the script for that. Perhaps one of these settings is the reason for your problem?

Comment: I'll give those a check. Could have sworn they were just set to Build, but it's possible that Build/Deploy was set instead. I'll also check the GenerateCreateScript property. I know that building the SLN instead gave me the desired result - just build. I stopped researching too much at that point. :-/